# Kafka consumers (same group-id) stucked in reading always from same partition

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, alpakka

I have 2 consumers running with the same group-id and reading from topic having 3 partititons and parsing messages with KafkaAvroDeserializer. The consumer has these settings:

```
  def avroConsumerSettings[T <: SpecificRecordBase](schemaRegistry: String, bootstrapServer: String, groupId: String)(implicit
  actorSystem: ActorSystem): ConsumerSettings[String, T] = {
     val kafkaAvroSerDeConfig = Map[String, Any](
       AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG -> schemaRegistry,
       KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG -> true.toString
     )
    val kafkaAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer()
    kafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(kafkaAvroSerDeConfig.asJava, false)
    val deserializer =
      kafkaAvroDeserializer.asInstanceOf[Deserializer[T]]

    ConsumerSettings(actorSystem, new StringDeserializer, deserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServer)
      .withGroupId(groupId)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")
  }
```

I tried to send a malformed message to test error handling and now my consumer is stucked (always retry reading from same partition because I'm using [RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/errorhandling.html#restarting-the-stream-with-a-backoff-stage)); but what is strange to me (AFAIK each consumer in the same group-id cannot read from the same partition) is that if I run another consumer it stucks as well because it reads again from the same partition where unreadable message is.

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to add a `consumerId` to your consumers and look at Kafka data to see which consumer is plugged to which partition.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find any help on how to manually assign an id to consumer. Can you provide any link?

Comment: Pretty sure you have a `withConsumerId` method on the `ConsumerSettings`

Comment: Nope...I only find withConsumerFactory as method with same intials (but it's not what i'm looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restart the Kafka source after a failure, that results in a new consumer being created; eventually the consumer in the failed source is declared dead by Kafka, triggering a rebalance.  In that rebalance, there are no external guarantees of which consumer in the group will be assigned which partition.  This would explain why your other consumer in the group reads that partition.

The issue here with a poison message derailing consumption is a major reason I've developed a preference to treat keys and values from Kafka as blobs by using the `ByteArrayDeserializer` and do the deserialization myself in the stream, which gives me the ability to record (e.g. by logging; producing the message to a dead-letter topic for later inspection can also work) that there was a malformed message in the topic and move on by committing the offset.  `Either` in Scala is particularly good for moving the malformed message directly to the committer.